# can query parameters be mandatory in REST API

Tags: java, rest, get, jax-rs

I have a requirement which says there has to be two parameters(one of them represents date) that are part of the GET URI have to be mandatory. But these two parameters are only for filtration purpose. So my question is,
**Can mandatory parameters be used as Query params?** (Or we can still use them as path params although there is no parent/child relationship)

Comment: Of course they can. For example an URI that requires `?id=` would be a mandatory parameter. But just because it's mandatory doesn't mean it has to be a path parameter.

Comment: but mostly it is seen they are used as optional.

Comment: They *can* be optional. If someone thinks they're *always* optional, they're thinking wrong. Since the server mandates what's required and what's not, getting a `400` from the server will at least clarify to the client that the GET parameter is not in fact "optional".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, mandatory parameters can be used in query parameters. In that case you need to put a validation after the API is hit to check whether the value of the parameter is not null and is of specified format. In case they fail to mention even the query parameter variable in the path, then they will end up receiving 404 error.

Comment: Not `404` (Not Found), but `400` (Bad Request).

Comment: Correction: It should give 404 if mandatory fields are not passed as query params leaving the URI improper.

Comment: @Satej wrong, 400 is the right status code