# Right way to express a range query in the kv storage via REST API?

Tags: rest, key-value-store

Imagine a simple kv store, that supports a range queries and uses integers as a keys.

`GET /kv/:key`

`PUT /kv/:key` (payload is the value)

`DELETE /kv/:key`

I'm thinking about `/kv/?from=1&to=100` but the idea of required query parameters is kinda ugly. What would be the right way to represent a range query via REST in a kv store?

Comment: Query parameter may be required and is a good idea.
Please see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61024499/can-query-parameters-be-mandatory-in-rest-api#:~:text=Yes%2C%20mandatory%20parameters%20can%20be,and%20is%20of%20specified%20format.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61024499/can-query-parameters-be-mandatory-in-rest-api#:~:text=Yes%2C%20mandatory%20parameters%20can%20be,and%20is%20of%20specified%20format.)